# Operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference in dot operator, colon operator and scope resolution operator in Ruby?

Where and why are they used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dot operator separates an object and a method belonging to that object, for example `"Hello".reverse` or

```
def self.my_singleton_method
end
```

This single colon isn't really an operator. It can be used in ruby 1.8 instead of `then` in an `if` or `case/when` statement. In ruby 1.9 it can be used in hash literals, e.g. `{A : 65}`. It precedes an identifier to form a Symbol, e.g. `:red`, and it's used in the ternary condition operator `?:`.

The *double* colon operator is the scope resolution operator. It specifies in which class or module you reference a constant. Note that classes and modules are themselves constants.

```
module MyModule
  class Object
  end

  p Object           # prints "MyModule::Object"
  p ::Object         # prints "Object"
end
```

Preceding a constant with `::` means that you take it from the outer, or global, scope.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is used for method calls

The `:` is used to define symbols

The `@` `@@` `$` is used to denote a scope